# Cobertura Checks Fail on Travis CI

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

In my Maven build, I use Cobertura to check that there is a certain minimal coverage:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <check>
            <branchRate>100</branchRate>
        </check>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>cobertura</goal>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When running `mvn install`, this works fine. However, in Travis CI, the build fails because Travis [first runs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java#Dependency-Management) `mvn install -DskipTests=true` to get the dependencies. Obviously, when tests are skipped, there is no coverage, and therefore the whole build fails:

```
[ERROR] ch.trick17.betterchecks.fluent.StringCheck failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 100.0%
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2:check (default) on project better-checks-core: Coverage check failed. See messages above. -> [Help 1]
```

Can I somehow configure Cobertura to skip the check if tests are skipped? Or is there any other solution, maybe on the Travis side?

---

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: java

jdk:
  - openjdk6
  - openjdk7
  - oraclejdk7
  - oraclejdk8

script: "mvn install"
```

Comment: What are you running an `install` step on Travis...in the majority of the cases it is not needed. So only the script step is needed.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the comment, but I think the problem has nothing to do with the specified script (see updated answer), since Travis runs `mvn install -DskipTests=true` anyway.

Comment: You can turn that of by using: `install: true` which [skips the install step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/).

Comment: Oh, now I see what you meant. Not knowing the install step even existed, I thought you were talking about my `mvn install` command. So thank you for your comments, they will probably solve the issue (working on it right now). Do you what to post it as an answer? If not, I will write it up myself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn that of by using: `install: true` [which skips the install step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-the-Installation-Step).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to kmarbaise's answer, instead of completely turning off the install step, you can replace customize it so that it [skips the Cobertura check](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#Optional_Parameters):

```
install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dcobertura.skip=true -B -V
```

This way, the output of your actual build script will not be cluttered with output from downloading the dependencies and Maven plugins.